# How to check logs in MongoDB that hosted using Kubernetes?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I found out that my database that was hosted on Kubernetes constantly getting removed all the data in a collection after some time. I want to make sure it isn't some sort of deployment or config error so I would like to check the logs of MongoDB itself.

I tried `kubectl logs <mongodb-pod-name>` but it only logs the connection and disconnection to the mongodb pod. Would like to access to `mongodb.log` file to check if the data is removed automatically or someone had executed a command to remove it.

The mongo db is hosted on Amazon EKS.

Is it possible or there is any other way that I can investigate this issue?
Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

You can:

`kubectl describe pod <mongodb-pod-name>`

Then, you can access the container :

```
kubectl exec --stdin --tty <mongodb-pod-name>  -- /bin/bash
```

or:

```
  kubectl exec --stdin --tty <mongodb-pod-name>  -- sh
```

And see logs inside the container

Comment: The container id is something like this: `Container ID:   docker://<some-id>`. When I run docker logs command, it show me: `Error: No such container`.

Comment: Yes, I tried with `docker logs some-id` with or without the `docker://` Not sure if its related but my container is hosted on Amazon EKS, not running in local.

Comment: After access to the bash, which command should I execute to see the logs inside container? `docker logs` won't work.

Comment: to see the logs :`tail -n200 /path/to/mongo/logfile`

Comment: Thanks! I think there is no log file existed in my case... `tail -n200 /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log` shows No such file existed. And `ls -al /var/log/mongodb` shows nothing under the directory... Guess I will have to find another way to try investigate the data losss issue... Anyhow thanks for your help!

Comment: basically, you should know yaml configuration file(deployment file ) at the beginning of deployment, ex: log streaming integration, cloudwatch integration, image, ...

Comment: Sadly I did not integrate any of those because it was a spike for trying out MongoDB on EKS. I would try figured out other way to check the issue. Thanks for your help!